# SQL Server Error Message Box on startup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

Every time I reboot my machine I see the attached error message.
This seems to be a recent occurance since I upgraded SQL Server Express Edition (with advanced services) to SQL Server Developer Edition.

I am also unable to access my Reporting Services Configuration Manager, When I type in my local machine name and click find and it says "Invalid Class"

Does anyone know if the two are related and what the problem seems to be?[image]

Comment: I'm not sure about your first problem but for the second one i think Reporting service configuration manager cannot find the instance name automatically

Answer (score 0):

Can you please Open the

```
Start Menu > All Programs > Microsoft SQL Server > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Configuration Tools
```

Check whether your **SQL Server** and **Reporting Services** are started or not? If they are stopped you have to start them, Some Anti Visures may close the ports that SQL Server is using

When you ensure that you are running SQL Server and the reporting services, you have to Open

```
Start Menu > All Programs > Microsoft SQL Server > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Reporting Service Configuration Manager
```

And check if you can connect to Reoprting Services or not, Let me know what's happen then, And I will continue

Comment: Both services are running, however when I go to Reporting Services Configuration Manager and click 'Find' next to my machine name it says 'Invalid Class' I am currently using my machine as a temp reporting server and used to be able to get into this screen.

Comment: @SelectDistinct When SASRS Configuration Manager cannot find the instance of Reporting Services you definately missed a file or dll. Usually it is hard to find missed dll so in the mean time, you would better **Repair SQL Server**